# Problem wih fseek and Microsoft's CRT UNICODE support

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to read a UTF8 encoded text file using the unicode streams. This works fine, but there seems to be a bug with `fseek` demonstrated with following simple file and program:

**The text file I'm reading:**

```
ABC
```

**Raw content of the file**

```
EF BB BF 41 42 43 0D 0A
```

As you can see the file contains the UTF-8 BOM and the characters ABC followed by an end of line.

The program opens the file using UNICODE support, then it reads one line and displays the raw content of the buffer, which is as expectd. Then it fseeks to the beginning and reads the line again, but this time the content of the buffer is different; there are two bytes at the beginning of the buffer which are actually the BOM for UTF-16 little endian encoded files.

**Program**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *input = _wfopen(L"utf8filewithbom.txt", L"r, ccs=UTF-8");
  if (input == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }

  unsigned char buffer[100];
  fgetws((wchar_t*)buffer, _countof(buffer) / 2, input);
  printf("First 4 bytes of buffer: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);

  fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);

  fgetws((wchar_t*)buffer, _countof(buffer) / 2, input);
  printf("First 4 bytes of buffer: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);

  fclose(input);
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
First 4 bytes of buffer: 41 00 42 00
First 4 bytes of buffer: 41 00 42 00
```

**Actual output:**

```
First 4 bytes of buffer: 41 00 42 00
First 4 bytes of buffer: ff fe 41 00
```

Is this a bug in the Microsoft CRT or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.3.

**Things I tried but that didn't change anything:**

- using `"rt, ccs=UTF-8"` instead of `"r, ccs=UTF-8"`
- reading a UTF-16 little endian encoded file instead of an UTF-8 encoded file

Comment: Have you tried use "rt, ccs=UTF-8" instead of just "r, ccs=UTF-8"?

Comment: @SimonMourier same result

Comment: From remarks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-160#remarks this is expected. You'd have to use ftell just after the first fgetws to know where to go back to the beginning.

Comment: It seems they missed a trick by not bothering to support UTF-16BE (with or without BOM).

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I also wondered why they don't support UTF-16BE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the Microsoft docs on `fseek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-160):

> When the CRT opens a file that begins with a Byte Order Mark (BOM), the file pointer is positioned after the BOM (that is, at the start of the file's actual content). If you have to `fseek` to the beginning of the file, use `ftell` to get the initial position and `fseek` to it rather than to position 0.

Basically, just tweak your code to (comments on changed/added lines):

```
  FILE *input = _wfopen(L"utf8filewithbom.txt", L"r, ccs=UTF-8");
  if (input == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    return 1;
  }
  const long postbomoffset = ftell(input); // Store post-BOM offset

  unsigned char buffer[100];
  fgetws((wchar_t*)buffer, _countof(buffer) / 2, input);
  printf("First 4 bytes of buffer: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);

  fseek(input, postbomoffset, SEEK_SET);  // Seek to post-BOM offset, not raw beginning

  fgetws((wchar_t*)buffer, _countof(buffer) / 2, input);
  printf("First 4 bytes of buffer: %02x %02x %02x %02x\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);

  fclose(input);
```

Comment: Makes  sense, I missed that in the documentation. But TBH this should be transparent, IMO this is a design flaw.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I mostly agree. Downside to transparent handling is that it denies the programmer the ability to rewind to look at the BOM (they may have specific a `ccs` encoding, but want to check if the file had a BOM that overrode it, or when rewriting the file in place, may want to replace it, etc.). The fundamental problem is that they are tacking on encoding support to a set of APIs developed nearly 50 years ago, in a time when Unicode literally didn't exist, and text encoding was "whatever the current machine uses" (because who moves data between machines?). There are bound to be warts.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Side-note: It's probably a better idea to use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`, rather than `ftell` and `fseek`; while in this case, you're probably okay, `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` handle arbitrarily large files (where `fseek` and `ftell` are `long` based, which means they have issues for files larger than 2 GB, since Windows uses 32 bit `long`s even in 64 bit mode; the MS specific `_fseeki64` and `_ftelli64` functions can fix this part), and they (in theory) have some safety features to deal with text files in multibyte encodings (where `fseek` and `ftell` are fundamentally byte-based).